# First Order Problem $∃x(¬P(x) \land ¬Q(x)) \to ∃x(¬(P(x) \land Q(x)))$

Tags: first-order-logic

How do I prove this sequent using First Order Logic?

$∃x(¬P(x) \land ¬Q(x)) \vdash ∃x(¬(P(x) \land Q(x)))$

Thinking, according to DeMorgan:
$ \lnot(¬p \lor ¬q) = \lnot(p \land q) $ this is true, so, why the other one is true? how do I prove it?

EDIT:

I'm using Predicate logic and i got the problem from the book: Logic in Computer Science 2nd ed.

Comment: Which first order logic are you using?  Where did you get this problem?

Comment: update description:  I'm using Predicate logic and i got the problem from the book: Logic in Computer Science 2nd ed.

Comment: Predicate logic is less specific than first order logic.  What are your axioms / inferences?

Comment: Now you got me! i'm using this rules:
1. ∃x addition and exclusion
2. $\forall x$ addition and exclution
3. and the propositional logic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus
here is the First Order Logic wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic

Comment: So you are using natural deduction it sounds like?  And a link to wikipedia's *entire article* on propositional logic is not a list of axioms/inferences.  There are gazillions of specifications of propositional logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a direct natural deduction proof.  The basic idea is, since $\lnot Px \land \lnot Qx \vdash \lnot (Px \land Qx)$ (lines 2 through 7), use Or elimination to remove the first $\exists$ and Or intro to introduce the final $\exists$ (the remaining lines).

$$\begin{array} {rll}
%
(1) &  \exists x ~(\lnot Px \land \lnot Qx) & \text{Premise} \\
%
(2) & \quad \quad \lnot Py \land \lnot Qy & \text{Premise} \\
%
(3) & \quad \quad \lnot Py & \text{And Elimination of 2} \\
%
(4) & \quad \quad \quad \quad Py \land Qy & \text{Premise} \\
%
(5) & \quad \quad \quad \quad Py & \text{And Elimination of 4} \\
%
(6) & \quad \quad \quad \quad \bot & \text{Contradiction of 3 and 5} \\
%
(7) & \quad \quad \lnot (Py \land Qy) & \text{Not Introduction of 4 through 6} \\
%
(8) & \quad \quad \exists x ~ \lnot (Py \land Qy) & \text{Exists Intro of 7} \\
%
(9) & \exists x ~ \lnot (Px \land Qx) & \text{Exists Elimination of 1, and 2 through 8} \\
%
\end{array}$$